# Is there a way to add export data option on top of a plotly chart, without using dash?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a static HTML report. I have created some plotly charts but need to give the user the option of downloading the corresponding data. Is there a way it can be done in pythonic way? Another alternative can be, the ability to download the plotly table data as a csv. Keeping in mind I really don't want to create a web-app but a sharable static HTML output I am not using plotly dash or widgets. Below is the code I used to create a plot and a table with plotly dropdown button, I want to create a button/link to give the user option to download the table or the underlying data as csv or excel. I saw this option in R Flex dashboard and in Python D-Tale but haven't been able to breakthrough in Python notebook.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.iris()
species_list = sorted(set(df['species']))

# --- function ---

def make_multi_plot(df1, item_list):

    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, 
                        cols=2,
                        #shared_xaxes=True,
                        #vertical_spacing=0.2,
                        specs = [[{}, {"type": "table"}]]
                            
                       )

    for item_id in item_list:
            #print('item_id:', item_id)
            
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
                x=df1.loc[df1.species.isin([item_id])].sepal_length, 
                y=df1.loc[df1.species.isin([item_id])].sepal_width,
                mode='markers',
                name = str(item_id)
        )
        fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
            
            
        trace2 = go.Table(
                columnorder = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                columnwidth = [2,2,2,2,4,2],
                header=dict(
                    values = ["sepal<br>length","sepal<br>length","petal<br>length","petal<br>width","species","species<br>id"],
                    font = dict(size=10),
                    align = "left"
                ),
                cells = dict(
                    values = [df1[df1.species.isin([item_id])][k].tolist() for k in df1[df1.species.isin([item_id])].columns[:]],
                    align = "left"
                )
            )
        fig.append_trace(trace2,1,2)
        
    Ld = len(fig.data)
    #print(Ld)
    Lc = len(item_list)
        
    for k in range(2, Ld):
        fig.update_traces(visible=False, selector=k)
    
    def create_layout_button(k, item_id):
            #print(k, item_id)
            
        visibility = [False]*2*Lc
        for tr in [2*k, 2*k+1]:
                visibility[tr] = True
                
            #print(visibility)
                
        return dict(label = item_id,
                        method = 'restyle',
                        args = [{'visible': visibility,
                                 'title': item_id
                                 }])    
    
    #updatemenu[0]['x'] = 0
    #updatemenu[0]['xanchor'] = 'left'
    #updatemenu[0]['y'] = 1.2
    #updatemenu[0]['yanchor'] = 'top'
    fig.update_layout(
           updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
               active=0,
               buttons=[create_layout_button(k, item_id) for k, item_id in enumerate(item_list)],
               x=0.5,
               y=1.3
           )],
           #title='Model Raporu',
           #template='plotly_dark',
           #height=800
           xaxis_title="Sepal_Length",
           yaxis_title="Sepal_Width"
        )
    
    fig.show()

# --- main ---
make_multi_plot(df1=df, item_list=species_list)
```